# Divisibility of a series

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I use the notation $123 \dots (z)$ to represent a number that looks like a concatenated string of consecutive integers up to $z\in \mathbb{N}$. E.g. $123 \dots (15)$ denotes $12346789101112131415$.

I have observed the following pattern:

> If $p|123\dots (p)$ , $q|123\dots (q)$ , **gcd(p,q)<=2**, then $pq|123\dots (pq)$.

Excluding p or q is 69, is this true.For example $2|12$ and $3|123$, so $6|123456$. Can  you prove or disprove the statement? Additionally, what is the rule when $p=q$?

Also, if my aim is to determine whether n|123...(n), what can we do to those n is a prime or 8|n

---

**P.S**. I'm sorry i made so much mistakes. this is a question i investigate on long time ago and it suddenly comes up to me today, I'm sorry I have forgotten some of the details

Comment: No idea what you mean by "p|123......p"

Comment: you can see my example upthere

Comment: There aren't many cases where $pq<10$. Really just $2,3$ and $2,4$.

Comment: The bar symbol as in  $x|y$ means that $x$ divides $y$ (both integers) with no residue, i.e. $y$ is an integer multiple of $x$

Comment: Yes, and your example wasn't clear enough,  if you want help on this site, you need to make at least some effort to state your questions clearly and to be responsive when people tell you they're not clear.

Comment: i understand my mistake

Comment: a and b are all nactural number. my first sentence is misleading. i just want to mean 123,,,,p altogether is a number

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing the post. Please make sure my edits accurately capture the question you want to ask.

Comment: Many thanks to you. I'm not a native english speaker, so the original version  is a bit strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers $n$ such that $n$ divides $12\dots(n)$ are tabulated at http://oeis.org/A029455. $3$ and $27$ are in the list, but $3\times27=81$ is not, so it's a counterexample. So is $p=9$, $q=27$; also, $p=18$, $q=27$, and $p=27$, $q=36$, and doubtless many others.

Perhaps more interesting: if OEIS is right, then $p=69$ works, but $2\times69$ doesn't, neither $3\times69$, $5\times69$, and so on.

Comment: I see your point. It seems that the restriction p=q is not strong enough.

Comment: editions have been made

Comment: many thanks for your website provided

Comment: So every time someone disproves your statement, you're going to change the question? No, that's not the way to do mathematics. Anyway, there are still plenty of counterexamples, but I'll let you find them.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the smallest counterexample, but 
$$
  12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940
$$ 
is not divisible by $40$ even though $1234567891011121314151617181920$ is divisible by $20$ and $12$ is divisible by $2$.

Comment: editions have been made